# How to load business objects inherited from data layer (new answers are welcomed)

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4, casting, layer, n-tier-architecture

I have a Data layer and Business layer in my App.
In data layer I have imported database tables as objects using entity framework.
One of them is **Unit** table for example.
Now in business layer I want to add some methods to Unit of data layer so I have this class:

```
namespace Business.Entity
{
    public class Unit : Data.Unit 
    {
     //Some business affairs here
    } 
}
```

And for loading units in UI I have created a repository in business layer :

```
    public static IEnumerable<Data.Unit> LoadUnits()
    {
        return from entity in StaticDataContext.Units select entity;
    }
```

Everything is good till now.

But I want to load a list of **Business.Unit** in UI so I wrote this one:

```
    public static IEnumerable<Business.Entity.Unit> LoadUnits()
    {
        var result = (from entity in StaticDataContext.Units
                      select entity).ToList().Cast<Business.Entity.Unit>();
        return result;
    }
```

It compiles well but then I get this runtime error when binding it to a Grid:

```
InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Data.Unit' to type 'Business.Entity.Unit'
```

Can any one say how to arrange the classes to be able to load business classes in UI ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not directly cast parent object to child object. Possible solutions for your problem:

1. Create in `Business.Entity.Unit` class a constructor accepting `Data.Unit` as argument and assigning all necessary properties, like:

   ```
   namespace Business.Entity
   {
       public class Unit : Data.Unit 
       {
           public Unit(Data.Unit parent)
           {
               // Assign proprties here
           }
           //Some business affairs here
       } 
   }
   ```

   After that you can do:

   ```
   public static IEnumerable<Business.Entity.Unit> LoadUnits()
   {
       var result = (from entity in StaticDataContext.Units
                     select new Business.Entity.Unit(entity)).ToList().Cast<Business.Entity.Unit>();
       return result;
   }
   ```
2. Rewrite your `Business.Entity.Unit` class so that it does not inherit `Data.Unit`, but accepts `Data.Unit` entity as a constructor parameter, aggregates it (stores in a local private member) and presents wrapper properties and functions to operate on it
3. Remove your `Business.Entity.Unit` class entirely and implement all additional methods as [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).

I'd vote for the third one because IMHO it leaves code a bit cleaner and does not have overhead of introducing and managing additional entity.

Comment: Extension methods was good idea. But I want to strict to multitier application disciplines. Let's see anyone have any other solution.

Comment: And also by evading inheritance I will lose Navigation feature of data layer objects.

Comment: If you decide to avoid inheritance then anyway you can expose navigation properties using appropriate wrappers around original properties of aggregated object. There might be also solution 4) use Repository pattern and move your business logic to static methods of appropriate repository class.

Answer (score 1):

Try following approach, return your class `Business.Entity.Unit` objects list rather than casting to another class.

```
public static IEnumerable<Business.Entity.Unit> LoadUnits()
        {
            var result = (from entity in StaticDataContext.Units
                          select new Business.Entity.Unit { 
                          ///set properties of this class as 
                          Id = entity.ID, .. son  
                          }).ToList();
            return result;
        }
```

I suggest you to go through ScottGu's article on [Code-First Development with Entity Framework 4](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx).

Comment: It works good but does it give me the navigation that EntityFramework gives with its objects to us ? I mean by this way I don't have for example **Unit.Instruments** . And another issue is that by this method I have to transfer all objects fields data from data to business which is very time consuming.